# Finding the next President - PHP Arrays and Validation

Tags: php, arrays

Hmm So I've updated my code.  For those who don't know, I'm trying to make a form where the user answers who the next president will be from a drop down.  If correct, on to the next president; if wrong, they have to keep guessing but their attempts will increment.  For some reason, my form is not recognizing who the next president will be.  I don't think $questionpres (initially "George Washington") is passing through to handleform($president).

```
  <?php
    $president = array(
        "George Washington"=>"John Adams",
        "John Adams"=>"Thomas Jefferson",
        "Thomas Jefferson"=>"James Madison",
        "James Madison"=>"James Monroe",
        "James Monroe"=>"John Quincy Adams",
        "John Quincy Adams"=>"Andrew Jackson",
        "Andrew Jackson"=>"Martin Van Buren",
        "Martin Van Buren"=>"William Henry Harrison",
        "William Henry Harrison"=>"John Tyler",
        "John Tyler"=>"James K. Polk",
        "James K. Polk"=>"Zachary Taylor",
        "Zachary Taylor"=>"Millard Fillmore",
        "Millard Fillmore"=>"Franklin Pierce",
        "Franklin Pierce"=>"James Buchanan",
        "James Buchanan"=>"Abraham Lincoln",
        "Abraham Lincoln"=>"Andrew Johnson",
        "Andrew Johnson"=>"Ulysses S. Grant",
        "Ulysses S. Grant"=>"Rutherford B. Hayes",
        "Rutherford B. Hayes"=>"James Garfield",
        "James Garfield"=>"Chester A. Arthur",
        "Chester A. Arthur"=>"Grover Cleveland",
        "Grover Cleveland"=>"Benjamin Harrison",
        "Benjamin Harrison"=>"Grover Cleveland",
        "Grover Cleveland"=>"William McKinley",
        "William McKinley"=>"Theodore Roosevelt",
        "Theodore Roosevelt"=>"William Howard Taft",
        "William Howard Taft"=>"Woodrow Wilson",
        "Woodrow Wilson"=>"Warren G. Harding",
        "Warren G. Harding"=>"Calvin Coolidge",
        "Calvin Coolidge"=>"Herbert Hoover",
        "Herbert Hoover"=>"Franklin D. Roosevelt",
        "Franklin D. Roosevelt"=>"Harry S. Truman",
        "Harry S. Truman"=>"Dwight D. Eisenhower",
        "Dwight D. Eisenhower"=>"John F. Kennedy",
        "John F. Kennedy"=>"Lyndon B. Johnson",
        "Lyndon B. Johnson"=>"Richard M. Nixon",
        "Richard M. Nixon"=>"Gerald R. Ford",
        "Gerald R. Ford"=>"James Carter",
        "James Carter"=>"Ronald Reagan",
        "Ronald Reagan"=>"George H. W. Bush",
        "George H. W. Bush"=>"William J. Clinton",
        "William J. Clinton"=>"George W. Bush",
        "George W. Bush"=>"Barack Obama",
        "Barack Obama"=>"George Washington");
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <title>President Flashcards</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        body{ font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; }
        fieldset {  
            height: 200px; 
            width: 290px;
            background-image: url(whitehouse.jpg); 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        legend {
            background-color: gold; 
            width: 300px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        select {
            background-color: gold; 
            font-size: 18px;
            height: 40px;
        }
        input.mybutton {
            height:40px;
            float:right;
            font-size: 26px;
            background-color:gold;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-family:arial;
            position:relative;
            bottom:-50px;
          }
        .status {
            background-color: green;
            color: gold;
            position:relative;
            bottom:-100px;
        }   
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <pre>
    <?php //print_r($_GET); ?>
    </pre>
    <?
        if (isset($_GET['answerpres'])) {
            handleForm($president);
        } else {
            $questionpres = "George Washington";
            $legend="Who comes after $questionpres?";
            displayForm($president, $legend, $questionpres, 0, 0);
        }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    /* handleForm - this function handles a submitted form.  It determines if the user
     * selected the correct president.
     * Argument - the array of president/next presidents
     * Called by - main
     * Calls - displayForm
     * If the correct president is selected, 
     *          increment total and correct, 
     *          create the legend with the "correct" message
     *          call displayForm
     * If the incorrect president is selected
     *          increment total only
     *          create the legend with the "incorrect" message
     *          call displayForm
     */
    function handleForm($president){
        echo "Next is $president[$questionpres]";
        if($_GET['answerpres'] == $president[$questionpres]) {
            $total++;
            $correct++;
            $questionpres = $president[$questionpres];
            $legend = "Correct! Who comes after $questionpres?";
            displayForm($president, $legend, $qpres, $correct, $total);
        } else {
            $total++;
            $legend = "Incorrect. Who comes after $questionpres?";
            echo "You selected".$_GET['answerpres'];


            displayForm($president, $legend, $questionpres, $correct, $total);
            }
    }?>
    <?php
    /*
     * displayForm - displays the input form
     * Called by - handleForm
     * Calls -  makepresidentmenu
     * Arguments - the array of president/next presidents
     *           - the legend for the form's fieldset
     *           - the president the user will be asked about
     *           - the number of correct answers the user has given
     *           - the total number of answers the user has given.
     */
    function displayForm($president, $legend, $questionpres, $correct, $total){
    ?>
    <fieldset style="background-img=url(whitehouse.jpg); width:640px; height:343px;">
    <legend><? echo $legend ?></legend>
    <form>
    <? makepresidentmenu($president, $menuname, $currentpres); ?>

    <input type = "submit" name = "formsubmitted" value = "Submit" /></form>

    <div style="color:yellow; background:green; margin-top:100px; text-align:center; border:3px solid white;"> 
        <? echo "You have $correct of $total correct."; ?> 
    </div> 

    </fieldset> 

    <? } ?>

    <?php
    /*
     * makepresidentmenu - make a selection menu with all the presidents.  
     * Called by - displayForm
     * Calls - ksort
     * Arguments - the array of president/next presidents
     *           - the menu name
     *           - the current selection, defaults to NONE
     * Note that the displayed name and the value are the keys of the array.
     */
     function makepresidentmenu($president, $menuname, $currentpres = "")
    {
        ksort($president);
        echo "<select name='answerpres'>";
        //$key is current president.  $value is next president
        foreach ($president as $key => $value){
            if ($currentpres == $key)
                echo "<option value=\"$key\" selected> $key </option>\n";
            else
                echo "<option value=\"$key\"> $key </option>\n";
        }
        echo "</select>\n";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include your actual output and the contents of the $president variable as passed.

Comment: I see you updated this with more information, but you're still lacking what output you get.  For instance, Does it always give "John Adams" as the correct next president?  Does it always record a wrong answer regardless of what answer is given?  These are details required to debug this properly.

Comment: It always says "Incorrect.  Who is the next President after George Washington?" even when I select "John Adams".  And when I answer again, the counter stops incrementing as though the form isn't submitting after the first submit.

Answer (score 0):

The whole function is a little bit confusing.. why is `total`, `current` and `qpres` local defined? This values never change, if you call the function twice. You have to store information like this serverside in a session.
Is there a special reason why is `president` an parameter for the function? Doesn't make much sense for me.
Initialize qpres with an string(not index) is also a little bit strange.

```
$president = array(
    "George Washington",
    //...
);

function handleForm($president) {
    $qpres = $president[$_SESSION["qpres"]];
    echo "$qpres is the next president";
    if($_GET['answerpres'] == $_SESSION["qpres"]) {
        $_SESSION['total']++;
        $_SESSION["correct"]++;
        $qpres = $president[$qpres];
        $legend = "Correct! Who comes after $qpres?";
        displayForm($president, $legend, $_SESSION["qpres"], $_SESSION["correct"], $_SESSION['total']);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['total']++;
        $legend = "Incorrect. Who comes after $qpres?";
        displayForm($president, $legend, $_SESSION["qpres"], $_SESSION["correct"], $_SESSION['total']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're experiencing is because you hardcode "George Washington".  You probably want to only set $qpres = "George Washington" if it's not already set. Perhaps make it:

```
if (empty($qpres)){
    $qpres = "George Washington";
}
```